# Javascript in google spreadsheet

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm creating a bracket for 2014 world cup using google spreadsheet. Google spreadsheet has a script editor which runs javascript i'm a complete newbie to javascript and need help creating a function or functions the following formulas into javascript:

```
//(B10 != B2 or B3) = 0 

//(J14 != B2 or B3) = 0

//(B10 = B2 or B3) = 2

//(J14 = B2 or B3) = 4

//(B10 = B2) and (J14 = B3) = 6
```

Comment: where is your function?

Comment: I don't have a function at the moment that's what i need help with function lastSixteen() {
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();B2:B3
  if 
(B10 != B2 or B3) = 0 
(J14 != B2 or B3) = 0
(B10 = B2 or B3) = 2
(J14 = B2 or B3) = 4
(B10 = B2) and (J14 = B3) = 6
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a good tutorial on how to create a tournament bracket spreadsheet with Google scripting.  It should be a good start for you

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/bracket_maker